# Product of elements in tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am having trouble understanding a part of a proof given in Dummit and Foote relating to tensor algebras. The theorem states: Suppose $M$ is any $R$ module where $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$. Then $\mathcal{T}(M)$ is an $R$-algebra with multiplication defined by the mapping $(m_1\otimes\cdots\otimes m_i)(m_1'\otimes\cdots\otimes m_j')=m_1\otimes\cdots\otimes m_i\otimes m_1\otimes\cdots\otimes m_j'$ and extended to sums via distributive law. With respect to this multiplication $\mathcal{T}^i(M)\mathcal{T}^j(M)\subseteq\mathcal{T}^{i+j}(M)$.

The proof starts as follows:The map $M\times\cdots\times M\times M\times\cdots \times M\rightarrow\mathcal{T}^{i+j}(M)$ defined by $(m_1,...,m_i,m_1',...,m_j')\mapsto m_1\otimes\cdots\otimes m_i\otimes m_1'\otimes\cdots\otimes m_j'$ is $R$-multilinear, so induces a bilinear map $\mathcal{T}^i(M)\times\mathcal{T}^j(M)$ to $\mathcal{T}^{i+j}(M)$.

Why does the multilinear map above induce this bilinear map? Does this somehow follow from the universal property for tensor products? I know in general multilinear maps induce homomorphisms from tensor products, but that doesn't seem to be what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It's not so clear, and there's actually some work to be done. However, the work is similar to the work done in Proposition 10.21: namely, the work is that Corollary 10.16 is used twice, and both uses are for only the part of proving that the ring multiplication is well-defined. I guess Dummit Foote assume the readers of Chapter 11.5 (specifically of Theorem 11.31) have also read Chapter 10.4 (specifically of Proposition 10.21 and Corollary 10.16).

[image]

(and then some parts with errors. see the official errata, 'most recently revised on February 14, 2018' or 'most recently revised on March 17, 2019')

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that $\varphi \colon T^i(M) \times T^j \rightarrow T^{i+j}(M), \big((m_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes m_i)
,(m^\prime_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes m^\prime_j)\big) \mapsto m_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes m_i \otimes m^\prime_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes m^\prime_j \\$
 is bilinear. For this you can use the R-multi lin. of the given map.

Comment: What do you think of my answer please?